# Ubuntu Server 20.04 network config

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dhcp, netplan

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed in virtual machine on my Windows Hyper-V host.
I'd like it to get IP address from my Windows DHCP-server in local network
But it doesn't work and I don't know why. Virtual machine with Windows with same configuration works fine.

**`ip a`** output:

```
1: lo: <L00PBACK,UP,L0WER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid.lft forever preferred.lft forever
 inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid.lft forever preferred.lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
 link/ether 00:15:5d:00:28:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:2818/64 scope link
    valid.lft forever preferred.lft forever
```

Content of `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Output of `sudo netplan --debug generate`

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.358: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.359: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.360: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.360: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.361: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.361: Generating output files..
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.362: openvswitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1818): DEBUG: 12:50:00.363: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:1818): GLib-DEBUG: 12:50:00.363: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
(generate:1818): GLib-DEBUG: 12:50:00.365: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

Output of `sudo netplan --debug apply`

```
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.513: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.514: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.515: He have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.516: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.517: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.518: Generating output files..
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.519: openvswitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1826): DEBUG: 12:53:09.520: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:1826): GLib-DEBUG: 12:53:09.521: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
(generate:1826): GLib-DEBUG: 12:53:09.523: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:eth0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:eth0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  
DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eth0
DEBUG:eth0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` output

```
cat: /etc/network/interfaces/: No such file or directory
```

`ls -al /etc/netplan`  output

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2    root    root    4096    Nov 26  14:01
drwxr-xr-x 106  root    root    4096    Nov 25  16:45
-rw-r--r-— 1    root    root    115     Nov 26  14:01   00-installer-config.yaml
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` output

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

`sudo lshw -C network` output

```
[77792.441265] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0     
[77792.442325] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.443250] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read       
[77792.444154] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.445145] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1, async page read       
[77792.446145] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 2 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.447102] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 2, async page read       
[77792.448088] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 3 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.449085] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 3, async page read       
[77792.450098] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.451058] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 4, async page read       
[77792.452411] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 5 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.453448] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 5, async page read       
[77792.454518] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 6 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.455569] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 6, async page read       
[77792.456646] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 7 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.457762] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 7, async page read       
[77792.458901] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[77792.460028] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read       
[77792.461166] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1, async page read       
    *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 1
        logical name: eth0
        serial: 00:15:5d:00:28:18
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=hv_netvsc duplex=full firmware=N/A link=yes multicast=yes speed=lGbit/s
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `ls -al /etc/netplan` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @user535733 networkd is used for servers, not NetworkManager.

Comment: @heynnema question was edited as you asked

Comment: Everything looks ok there. There may be a problem with your Windows Hyper-V host setup. Check if it's in bridged mode. Also, do you have a CD/DVD inserted in your sr0 drive... as it's reporting a number of errors. Bad disc or bad drive?

Comment: @heynnema Hyper-V host setup looks fine and my windows vm's are working good. Also, when I change '00-installer-config.yam' to use static IP, it works on Ubuntu too... There was no image in sr0 drive, so I removed it from configuration. There is no more I/O errors, but it didn't make affect to network problem

Comment: Everything you've put into your question looks fine. I don't know what's wrong with your configuration. Please keep me posted if you find a solution.